# CasperJS and PhantomJS trigger "site is offline" browser doesn't

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

So I'm trying to scrape a site (https://shop.advanceautoparts.com/) and I could access it normally for the past couple of weeks through CasperJS. When I try to do it now (as of like 2 days ago) I get an odd message saying that the website is offline:

[image]

When I try it off a normal browser or PhantomJS, I get the normal site. I've tried doing it off different computers, changing my IP, changing the User agent but nothing works.

**EDIT**

After trying the same thing on PhantomJS, after running the code about 5 times I got the same message. Is this something the site is doing to prevent scraping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I suspect the site knows you are scraping based on your user agent as you are hitting it mutltiple times</strike>

Maybe try randomising your useragent and seeing what happens.  ([see list here](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php))

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  pageSettings: {
    userAgent: "USE SOME OTHER USER AGENT HERE"
  }
});
```

However the site might also be blocking by IP address after a number of simultaneous requests. Therefore also try a) slowing down your script or b) navigating to different pages

**EDIT**

I have knocked together a testing script and all works for me. The **important** bit  is:

`casper.waitUntilVisible("#header-top", function() {`

[image]

HTH

Comment: So when I use selenium, I get a warning saying that there is a "parser-blocking script using document.write to insert". It seems like Chrome automatically blocks this so I would assume that that is how I'm getting blocked (CasperJS just can't load it). Any suggestions for getting rid of it? Changing page, useragent, or IP have had no effect.

Comment: Have edited answer. All works good if you apply `waitUntilVisible("#header-top"`